# How to stop redirection in the Theme My Login WordPress plugin when the key or login URL variables are invalid?

Tags: php, wordpress

In the [Theme My Login](https://wordpress.org/plugins/theme-my-login/) plugin, if users forget their password, they are emailed a reset password link which contains a key and a login. The URL takes the form:

> example.com/resetpass/?key=u5f9Y4U0FaMrpgy7RU&login=henrywright

After visiting the link, if `key` or `login` in the URL are invalid, the user is redirected to the lost password page. The code that does the redirect can be found here [includes/class-theme-my-login.php](https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/theme-my-login/branches/6.3/includes/class-theme-my-login.php). Specifically, inside the `template_redirect()` function (starting on line 247) you should see:

```
if ( is_wp_error( $user ) ) {
    $redirect_to = site_url( 'wp-login.php?action=lostpassword&error=invalidkey' );
    wp_redirect( $redirect_to );
    exit;
}
```

If the `key` or `login` variables are invalid, I'd like the user to remain on the same page i.e. take no action. How can I disable the redirect?

So far I have tried removing `wp_redirect()` which works but isn't good practice because I'd prefer not to modify the plugin core.

Comment: just comment out the wp_redirect line. I doubt there is a built in way to override this.

Comment: I don't want to modify the plugin core

Comment: Then you are out of luck - you want non standard functionality. I doubt there is any kind of hook you can use to override this behavior. If the plugin doesnt do what you want, edit it or find another plugin.

Comment: That isn't good advice. I believe there is a way to do it without modifying the plugin code, it just isn't apparent to either one of us right now :)

Comment: @user574632 after a bit more investigation, I found a way using the  `tml_request_{action}` hook provided by the plugin. See http://www.jfarthing.com/development/theme-my-login/action-reference/

Comment: Well done, i seriously would have just commented the code out, its usually 50/50 whether a plugin author has included hooks (or documented them). +1 for persistence.

Comment: @user574632 yes definitely. Good documentation is so valuable and a sign of a good plugin! Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution to be the `tml_request_{action}` hook. Example:

```
function tml_resetpass_action() {
    // do something
}
add_action( 'tml_request_resetpass', 'tml_resetpass_action' );
```

Ref: http://www.jfarthing.com/development/theme-my-login/action-reference/